# Арендовал VPS на ubuntu 20.04, недавно появились проблемы с ssh соединением с сервером

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, vps

1. Периодически при подключении к vps по ssh появляется ошибка:
   ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection refused
   От этой проблемы временно (минут на 15) помогает из консоли сайта поставщика vps прописать
   systemctl start sshd
2. Изначально при аренде vps дали ip и пароль от root пользователя, затем я создал обычного пользователя и добавил его в группу wheel, после этого у меня перестало работать подключение по ssh под root с таким выводом в терминале:
   Last login: Thu Apr  1 12:49:09 2021 from 
   Connection to  closed.
   Соединение закрывается, потому что в /root/.bashrc на автовыполнении при входе написана команда "exit".
   Редактирование файла временно решает проблему, но потом в файле опять появляется "exit".

Comment: 1. Надо изучить что происходит с sshd. Немного ослабит боль использование tmux или screen. Немного ослабит боль регулярный рестарт sshd.

Comment: 2. ~/.ssh/rc исполняется на старте сессии. Там можно отредактировать .bashrc.

Comment: Открытие по SSH доступ на root это плохая практика. Странно что он у вас открыт, т.к. по умолчанию стоит запрет на вход рута по SSH. Смените пароли на более надежные.